# What is the password to the Crosh Dev Shell?

Tags: linux

I want to install Linux on my Chromebook but can't get the password right. It says...

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

Password: 
CjrSorry, try again.
Password: 
facepunchSorry, try again.
Password: 
sudo: 2 incorrect password attempts
```

Help!!
I have a ASUS Pixel chromebook.

Comment: There is no "ASUS Pixel chromebook" on http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices and there are no insightful search results for such a device either. Usually there is no password set, is this your privately owned device or owned by a company/organization?

Comment: Zacharry Smith, if those are your passwords for your gmail, or other things, you might want to remove them

Answer (score 1):

It may help if you specify what Chromebook you have ie. Acer C720P (mine)

1. try generic passwords like `password` and `12345678`
2. Powerwash your device without enabling debug options
3. if that didn't work Powerwash with debug options, set the root password to one of your choosing
4. if that didn't work make a recovery drive using `chrome://recovery` or using [Chromebook Recovery Utility](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromebook-recovery-utili/jndclpdbaamdhonoechobihbbiimdgai) other wise skip to step
5. install by rebooting and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> with the recovery drive plugged in on the Dev Mode screen.
6. if you still have problems with the password call your Chromebook's Manufacturer for help
7. Install your chosen type of linux

.
recommendations I have are:

[Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton): great if you want to quickly switch between ChromeOS and Ubuntu/Debian, more for people that like both a lot (like me)

[Chrubuntu](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html) or [CHRX](https://github.com/reynhout/chrx): Great if you only want to use on but not the other very often. Great for beginners, unsure about a full Linux desktop

Full install: any Linux distro you want instructions [here](http://www.bodhilinux.com/w/chromebook-install-instructions/). Great for people that dislike ChromeOS

Windows: it is possible using the same steps as the full Linux install, but you use a windows installer. Great for people that absolutely hate Linux with all their heart
note:some drivers may be missing like touch-screens and track-pads like my Chromebook

Comment: Your *Full install* and *Chrubuntu* are almost the same. The Bodhi instructions tell you to enable the legacy boot payload with SeaBIOS which is what Chrubuntu can also setup and what is currently the default for chrx.org, an updated version of the abandoned Chrubuntu project. Full install and referring to RW_LEGACY is misleading here, have a look at [mrchromebox.tech](https://mrchromebox.tech/static/firmware.html) and [johnlewis.ie](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/)

Comment: @LiveWireBT yes, but Chrubuntu is  using custom kernels for Chromebooks,allowing for some touch-screens immediately, and is also easier to set up quickly while still having ChromeOS

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. You mixed up some terminology Chrubuntu, Bodhi are RW_LEGACY, Full (Install|ROM) refers to something different and in between is (UEFI) BOOT_STUB. It's preferable to direct users to an up to date project like chrx so they install a recent version of what ever Linux distro. GalliumOS has custom kernels too and runs on top of Ubuntu 16.04 with some other modifications.

Comment: chrubuntu automatically resizes ChromeOS partitions for it's own partitions and has better compatibility with chromebooks' hardware. A full install, if you want both, requires more work and has less compatibility like some touchscreens may take some work to... well... work

Comment: @LiveWireBT, I did mine first using Chrubuntu about 2 years ago, and more recently about 1yr ago with Crouton, I didn't know a (basically) new version of Chrubuntu was created, it was added to the answers along with Chrubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by NOT enabling debug features on the setup screen.

Well I'd say that was an important omission.

See *Debugging Features

Click Proceed. The system reboots and displays a dialog with password prompts
[OPTIONAL] Set the new root password.
Note: If you leave the root password blank, the password defaults to test0000.

Answer (score -1):

No password required just put

`sudo su`